# Reddest county in a blue-state 2016?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

I was looking into rural counties in blue states that vote Republican. I found one that stuck out: Eureka County. Its citizens cast almost 85% of their votes for Donald Trump. Is this the reddest county within a state carried by Hillary Clinton? Or is there a redder one still, probably in a midwestern state like Colorado?

Also: if Texas turned blue in 2016 due to massive Hispanic turnout, there would be counties in the >90% range that are in a state that votes Democratic.

Comment: I would expect counties in Oregon or Washington, as states that have _massive_ urban/rural divides with enough urban populace to be largely blue but eastern regions that are immensely (e.g. Matt Shea) red. (Though looking at e.g. https://www.politico.com/2016-election/results/map/president/oregon/ I don't see anything more than about 80%).

Comment: Look at Nevada and Colorado. I found a county called Kiowa in CO with almost 86% Trump votes. Nevada has a massive divide too.

Comment: The second question you're asking is hypothetical and probably can't be answered here.

Comment: That wasn't a question. The other one answered because Kiowa was >85% Trump. Claiborne, MS, the opposite (bluest county in a red state) was 86% Clinton and highly African-American.

Comment: @NumberFile Sorry. I think I misread "there would" as "would there" making it seem like a question to me. My bad.

Comment: Why was this question reopened when the OP accepted it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

[This related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53090/counties-where-trump-or-clinton-got-85-of-the-vote/53091) has the counties with greater than 85% of the vote for one candidate. Kiowa County, Colorado went 85.15% for Trump. Clairborne County, Mississippi went 86.45% for Clinton.